# can i disable output escape in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I realise that the title of this question may be inaccurate but I was wondering how I can use something like in XSLT to clean up characters in Javascript. For example I have a JSON which I use to extract certain information, one of which is a hotel name. The problem is the hotels that have an apostrophe in their names eg george's hotel. When i display this in Chrome or Firefox it works fine however in IE8 it gives me `george&apos;s`.

My code is:

```
var hotel_title = j.data.hotels[i].title
```

Ive tried:

```
var zz = escape(hotel_title);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the code where you display the string and how your json looks like. Without these information it's hard to answer your question properly.

Comment: Do you have `&apos;` in the JSON data instead of a `'`? If so, you should really address the problem at source (the JSON contains fragments of XML (`&apos;` is an XML construct, not an HTML one) instead of text).

Comment: @ThiefMaster & Quentin - thanks for the comments/suggestions, i realise that i can most likely address the issue from the JSON file(havent tried that yet), but what if i was given a JSON api and had no control over that side of things?

Comment: @Hatzi — Baseball bat to the API supplier? More seriously, you'd need to test the API to figure out exactly what was happening to the data (encoded as XHTML? Generic XML) and figure out all the edge cases, then write a routine to fix them up (maybe wrapping data in tags and pushing through an XML parser, maybe a (*gulp*) string substitution).

Comment: @Hatzi: Then, frankly, I'd filter out the `&apos;` by string-replacing it with `'` in your JS at the point of data reception. That is, once I'd ascertained that `&apos;` was a single edge case and that I could otherwise guarantee that the JSON data contained valid HTML.

Comment: @Quentin & Lightness Races in Orbit - Thanks for your feedback, its given me some ideas. Ill look into the JSON firstly and go from there.

Comment: @Quentin - basbeball bat would be a great idea if i had no control over the JSON. Moral of the story i guess is to have complete control of the information you provide, however you sometimes get various xmls etc from other sources beyond your control. Now that can be a nightmare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- **Your document is HTML**

  Chrome and Firefox are trying to be helpful by rendering `&apos;` as a `'` when they shouldn't (because `&apos;` is XML — and thus XHTML — *not* HTML), but really it's just confusing. IE is behaving properly by not replacing the entity with an `'`.

Or:

- **Your document is XHTML**

  IE is not detecting this properly, and thus is not replacing the entity with an `'`.

---

Your two possible solutions are:

- Explicitly set the document to be XHTML, not HTML

  *(not ideal if you want to support older IE)*
- Stop sending `&apos;` in your data from source; just write `'` in your JSON instead.

  *(you should do this)*

Comment: Explicitly setting the document to be XHTML means serving it with an `application/xhtml+xml` content-type, which will make older version of IE refuse to render it at all.

Comment: @Quentin: OK, so it's an inferior solution. However, we don't know the OP's browser reqs.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - thanks for the comment, at least i understand what's going on now, luckily, i do have access to the JSON, i just hoped their would be a simple solution in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Is the string in your JSON already html-encoded? If yes, you need to assign it to the `innerHTML` property of some object. If not, assign it to `innerText`.

Comment: No. `&apos;` indicates XML encoding, not HTML. There is no `&apos;` in HTML.

Comment: That might just mean he's using an xml escaping function when generating the JSON though.

Answer (score -2):

One simple solution would be

```
var elt = document.createElement("div");
elt.innerHTML = yourString;
unescapedString = elt.textContent;
```

Comment: No it wouldn't, `&apos;` is not an HTML entity, which is why it is being rendered "wrong" in IE in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin: I suggest that you run this code in, say, Chrome Developer Tools console (`Ctrl-Shift-J` in any page in Chrome) before downvoting valid answers.

Comment: From the question "When i display this in Chrome or Firefox it works fine however in IE8…". Chrome will recover from the using-`&apos;`-in-html error, so running that code in Chrome developer tools proves nothing.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: I suggest that you read the question, instead of posting invalid answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: LOL I need to be more careful reading "Crome" as "Chrome" :) Apologies.